# Access to SNOWFLAKE Database

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to access the SNOWFLAKE database in the 30-day trial that Snowflake provides and having issues. I am connected as ACCOUNTADMIN and still seeing the error. I tried granting permissions from SECURITYADMIN to ACCOUNTADMIN but still no luck. What am I missing here?

```
SELECT  *
FROM  SNOWFLAKE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DATABASES
```

> SQL compilation error: Database 'SNOWFLAKE' does not exist or not authorized.

Comment: May I please know what is this for?

Comment: What does it do? I am not sure if my original post was clear but I don't have access to the "SNOWFLAKE" in Snowflake DWH. So, I don't know where does this Employees table/your query comes from.

Comment: https://media1.giphy.com/media/l3V0H7bYv5Ml5TOfu/giphy.gif

Comment: In the upper right hand corner of the GUI, you can select the role, warehouse, database, and schema for the session (query window). Have you got that pointed to ACCOUNTADMIN? I don't know what happens in the free trial period, but we have all of our users set up so that the default session permissions are low.

Comment: @EricBrandt Thanks for your reply. I was able to figure that out after the humor from T.S.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to get the issue resolved:

```
SET DEV_ROLE = 'ACCOUNTADMIN';
USE ROLE IDENTIFIER($DEV_ROLE);

SELECT  *
FROM  SNOWFLAKE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DATABASES;
```

And it returns 3 records.

Comment: My guess is that had you just used `USE ROLE ACCOUNTADMIN` directly, you'd have been fine.  Some people get confused by the UI on what you are logged in as vs. the context that you are running queries under in your Worksheet.  Setting the role to a variable doesn't change anything.